# Proof for monotonic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

here's my last days problem...

$f$ and $g$ are continuous and defined in the closed interval $[a,b]$ with output in the $[a,b]$, $a\ne0$.
$f$ is monotonically increasing in  $[a,b]$ and $g$ is monotonically decreasing in  $[a,b]$.
Show that there is at least one $x$ in the open interval $(a,b)$ so that:
$b\cdot f(x) + a\cdot g(x) = x\cdot(a+b)$.

Any help?

Comment: what does $a<>0$ mean?

Comment: a is not 0. I'm sorry, didn't know how to write the "different" symbol. @SiddharthJoshi

Comment: The condition $a\ne 0$ makes no sense: If $a=0$ then $b\ne 0$, and we can let $a^*=-b$, $b^*=-a$, $f^*(x)=g(-x)$, $g^*(x)=f(-f)$

Comment: Here's a counterexample: $a=-1$, $b=1$, $f(x)=\frac{3+x}4$, $g(x)=\frac{-x}4$.

Comment: @JuniorNikkie: Take $f$ and $g$ two functions defined on $[-1,1]$ by $f(x) = (x-1)/2$ and $g(x) = (1 - x)/2$. According to your problem, the equation $f(x) - g(x) = 0$ should have at least one solution in $(-1,1)$. It is not true.

Comment: Hagen Von Eitzen and @ÉricGuirbal you guys are totally right, thank you. I will let my professor know :) What I do now? Should I delete my question because it makes no sense and doesn't help others or let it posted?

Comment: It is true if 0<a<b, as shown by the deleted answers.

Comment: @Michael which answers do you mean, admins deleted them?

Comment: @JuniorNikkie All wnserwers deleted their answers when noticing they couldn't solve the problem *as posed*. If the condition is changed to $(b>)a>0$ then straightforward evaluation of $h(x)=LHS-RHS$ at $x=a$ and $x=b$ should help a lot.